# Timeout on promise when trying to make a mongoose query during mocha testing

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js

I am currently experiencing issues when trying to make a mongoose query to my DB during unit tests. I am trying to get the user in order to use the data for that specific test. Ideally if there is a solution i can branch this into a before each hook but at the moment nothing I am trying is returning the object from the DB.

My test suite

```
 let assert = require('assert');
 let request = require('supertest');
 let mongoose = require('mongoose');

 let User = require('../app/models/User');

 it('should be able to update a user', function (done) {
 User.findOne({email: 'example@email.com'})
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user);
    done();
    }).catch(done);

    });

    after((done) => {
        done();
    });
});
```

I am currently getting this error:

```
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (E:\DWA\express-mvc\test\test.js)
```

I have not been able to progress the query far enough to test if it is a problem with retrieving the user or the actual code itself.

I have tests that run like this:

```
request(url)
        .post('/login')
        .send({email: 'example@email.com', password: 'password'})
        .expect(302)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            done();
        });
```

But I am unsure how to connect to the DB just for the single query to retrieve a user rather than using one of my routes to my controller

Comment: You never connect the database, so findOne is waiting until it triggers the mocha timeout

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Thank you for the reply. I kind of understand what you mean now, I have added some information in the original comment, do you know how I would go about connecting to the DB just to get the user back? Sorry I am a student so I am not experienced

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are trying to call findOne when not connected to the database.

---

You can initialize your software system before to run any Mocha test. For example, connect a database.

```
// ROOT HOOK Executed before the test run
before(async () => {
    // connect to the database here
});

// ROOT HOOK Excuted after every tests finished
after(async () => {
    // Disconnect from the database here
});
```